# Get UITableView's height

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have created a `UITableview` with custom `UITableViewCell`.The `UITableViewCell` contains `UILabels` and I have calculated the height of each cell based on the cells height.But how can I get the tableview height?Because based on the tableView's height I need to calculate
the height of scrollView
I have created a `UITableView` like this when a button is clicked:

```
-(IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{
    self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,327,[arr5 count]*205) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate=self;
    self.tableView.dataSource=self;
    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    float fscrview = 150 + self.tableView.frame.size.height + 20;
    testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);
  }
 - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {
  NSString *city1 = city.text;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0];
        CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
        CGSize bounds = [city1 sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
//similarly calculated for all 
   return (CGFloat) cell.bounds.size.height + bounds.height+bounds1.height+bounds2.height+bounds3.height+bounds4.height+bounds5.height;
  }
```

I am able to get tableViewCells height through this.How do I calculate/set the overall tableView's height after this?

And how to calculate ScrollView's height based on tableView's row/height?

Comment: You have calculated the height of each cell based on the cells height?

Comment: yes I calculated the height of each cell.I need to get the overall tableview height based on the height of each cell.?

Comment: @Sindhia i think you want to set the TableView height with its contentdata size means with total cell and after that add this tableview in scrollview with its full size.. so for that use the bellow my answer ..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `contentSize.height` property of `UITableView`.

I think you want to set the whole tableview with content size and then set the scrollview size related content of `UITableView` and for this use bellow code...

After add data or `reloadData` in `UITableView` just set bellow code..

```
    yourTableView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTableView.frame.origin.x,yourTableView.frame.origin.y, yourTableView.frame.size.width, yourTableView.contentSize.height);

    float ftbl = yourTableView.frame.origin.y + yourTableView.contentSize.height + 15;
    yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, ftbl);
```

**UPDATE:**

```
self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,327,[arr5 count]*205)style:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
self.tableView.delegate=self; 
self.tableView.dataSource=self;

[testscroll addSubview:self.tableView]; /// add this tableview in scrollview not in self.view
[self.tableView reloadData];
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.contentSize.height);
float ftbl = self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.contentSize.height + 15; 
testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, ftbl);
```

Comment: @Sindhia also add this code in your viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method ... or after you add  the data in tableview

Comment: I am creating tableView on button click.So should I write it like   self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,327,[arr5 count]*205)style:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
self.tableView.delegate=self;
self.tableView.dataSource=self;
self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake( self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y,self.tableView.frame.size.width,  self.tableView.contentSize.height);
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
float ftbl =  self.tableView.frame.origin.y +  self.tableView.contentSize.height + 15; testscroll.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, ftbl);

Comment: when I write like this I cannot see the tableview

Comment: @Sindhia heyyyyy you add this tableview in self.view dude.. not add in this just add it in scrollview dude.. now i update now i find the problem

Comment: I have a doubt paras.actually how many cells can a tableview display defaulty?

Comment: now here in your code you see whole results dude we set the contentSize for that requirement .. and also set the scrollview for see whole tableview...then here not required paging..

Comment: k we have set both here.No need to add anything right.Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22046/discussion-between-sindhia-and-paras-joshi)

Answer (score 4):

Very simplest way to get your UITableView height

```
- (CGFloat)tableViewHeight

{
   [tblData layoutIfNeeded];

   return [YOUR_TABLE_NAME contentSize].height;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

on iOS 8+ this worked to get the table view Height

```
CGFloat tableViewHeight = tableView.bounds.size.height;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `tableView.backgroundView.bounds.size.height` Should work

**Logic:**

- `UITableView` has a property, `backgroundView` which is "A table view’s background view is automatically resized to match the size of the table view."
- `backgroundView` is a `UIView` which has the property `bounds` which is a `CGRect` that "defines the size and position of the view."
- `CGRect` has a `size` property, `size` has a `height` property

QED

Comment: backgroundView is nil

Answer (score 2):

You also can use KVO to observer tableview's contentSize property and adjust what you need in other views.

Put it somewhere, e.g. in viewDidLoad:

```
[self.tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew|NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:nil];
```

Then implement observer:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSKeyValueChangeKey,id> *)change context:(void *)context {
      if (object == self.tableView) {
        self.scrollViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
      }
      else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context];
      }
    }
```