# How to calculate table height dynamically?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to calculate height for a UITableView dynamically. I thought I could do it doing the sum on `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`, the problem is that this method is only called for the first X cells and won't be called again for a new set until you scroll.

I'm using autolayout constraints, How can I calculate table view accuratelly?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119916/get-uitableviews-height

Comment: Who do you load your cells? via CoreDate or an array or so?

Comment: @M.Kremer: using an array

Answer (score 0):

You can call below method to get height of UILabel..

```
  - (CGFloat)heightForWidth:(float)width AndFont:(UIFont *)font ForString:(NSString *) yourTextValue
    {
        CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
        if (yourTextValue.length > 0) {
            CGRect frame = [yourTextValue boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(width, 999999) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: font } context:nil];
            size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height + 1);
        }
        return size.height;
    }
```

Another way to set dynamic height of a cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat 
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Comment: Do you have labels inside of the cells? I mean custom labels!

Comment: I'm not sure how this is related to my question. I'm trying to change the height of my tableview to avoid having scroll

Comment: This method 'func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell' 
will be only called for visible cells of screen .. so this method only called for the first X cells because first X cells are visible on screen...This is a feature of tableView..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but appending to your comment you can disable scroll view with:

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = true
```

And you can get the hight of all the cells with:

```
self.tableView.contentSize.height
```