# Dynamic height UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have cells that consist of a title, date and a number of hashtags.

Here's the storyboard's screenshot:

[Custom cell in storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQILr.png)

I've set the following in my ViewDidLoad:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

But haven't given any estimatedHeight for the tableView which I'll explain why.

Here's my customCell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var date: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var hashtagsView: UIView!

var item: Item? {
    didSet {
        configureCell()
    }
}

func configureCell() {
    if item = item {
        title.text = item!.title
        date.text = item!.date

//      The part where I calculate the sizes of hashtags to fit them in hashtagsView

        let totalWidth = CGRectGetWidth(hashtagsView.frame)
        print("TotalWidth: \(totalWidth)")
        .
        .
        .
        .
        print("Content: \(self.contentView.frame)")
        print("HashtagsView: \(self.hashtagsView.frame)")
    }
}
```

---

Here's the results:

**With tableView.estimatedHeight = 150**

```
TotalWidth: 240.0
Content: (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 119.666666666667)
HashtagsView: (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 128.0)
```

---

**Without estimatedHeight**

```
TotalWidth: 240.0
Content: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 43.6666666666667)
HashtagsView: (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 128.0)
```

---

**Recap**

When there is an estimatedHeight, cell's contentView doesn't print a correct width, but displays the cell's contents well like nothing's wrong (except for the hashtagsView).

When there's not an estimatedHeight, cell's contentView does actually print the correct width, which lets me calculate the hashtags frames, but the cells display with their default 44 height.

---

**Detailed Info**

Since I don't know how many hashtags there is, I'm trying to use the blank UIView to add the UIButtons programmatically. And for calculation purposes of the hashtags' buttons, I need to have the "width" of the cell's contentView, or the hashtagsView's, but when I set tableView.estimatedHeight, cell's width will be some arbitrary number (e.g. 240 in 6s Plus Simulator). And I just can't get the hashtagsView's width, even though I have no auto-layout issues.

And when I don't give tableView.estimatedHeight an estimation, I get the following:

[Custom cells without estimatedHeight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXA7V.png)

---

**Updated - An update asked by @EarlGray in the comments**

The hashtags are actually UIButtons I add them to the hashtagsView dynamically. I need to stretch the hashtagsView's height so it'll fit more than one line of hashtags.

I think I'll either need to subclass UIView and override layoutSubviews() to achieve fit vertical layout or add constraints to each subview (UIButtons) programmatically.

Doing what @VinodVishwanath said, setting estimatedRowHeight combined with explicit heights and vertical space constraints gives me this:

[image]

Which unables me to get the width of the hashtagsView. During the calculations of the UIBUttons' frames, I need the cell.contentView's width, but somehow, setting the estimatedRowHeight gives me the following coordinates for the cell.contentView.frame

```
 Content: (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 119.666666666667)
```

Which is incorrect, because it has to give 414, and that's why my hashtags start from half of the screen.

Commenting out tableView.estimatedRowHeight gives me the correct coordinates:

```
Content: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 43.6666666666667)
```

But messes my tableView like so:

[image]

---

**Update #2 - Here's my constraints for the cell.contentView**

[ContentView's constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwmZF.png)

---

**Update #3 - A breakpoint on my configureCell method**

[HashtagsView's superview returns nil!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJU7K.png)

I don't get it, my UIView IBOutlet is connected, I double checked.

All of the contentView.subviews have incorrect frames. So does the superview-less hashtagsView.

But when I remove estimatedRowHeight, it suddenly considers hashtagsView as a subview of cell's contentView. Except for contentView, it's subviews frames' still return incorrect and negative values.

Comment: This link may help you to calculate height of cell:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36095091/3918500

Comment: Can you please update your post to explicitly confirm or deny whether you want to support live editing with multiline support? By that I mean if I set enough hashtags they will overflow to next line?

Comment: @EarlGrey Yes, I do want to support that. But I don't think it's live editing or maybe I didn't quite understand you. Cause I don't want to let the user edit anything. I just want the hashtags flow to the next line without ruining the self-sizing custom uitableviewcells

Comment: I am not interested in far hypothetical future..is your intent NOW to support resizing the cell as you type or not? Is this not happening part of the problem or not?  Where (which new line) do the hastags overflow if the cell already has some height? What If I have 10 hastags that take 3 lines? Because your screenshot for the cell shows an editable text control inside the cell.

Comment: @EarlGrey No my cells are not editable. There is a number of hashtags that must be dynamically set in each cell, thus making the cells flexible in height. And yes, right now I want to support vertical layout of the hashtags (UIButtons) in their own hashtagsView. I've updated my post, check it out please.

Comment: @iOS_Binod I checked your answer, this can be an option too, haven't tried it yet, but I think setting estimatedRowHeight combined with proper management of AutoLayout on cells will solve the issue. Yet for now, I can't get the cell's width with estimatedRowHeight. I'll try your solution if I couldn't find any easier ones.

Comment: fgs - you say cell are not editable and then you say hasthtags are set dynamicaly - adding spmething dynamically means it shows up in the cell after the cell showed up on screen. Do you need the cell to resize after it showed up on screen already or do you only need to have individual sizes to cells but once a cell shows up it will keep its individual size?

Comment: @EarlGrey Nothing is going to get edited when the cell shows up, I meant I'll have to set the hashtags dynamically, and by dynamically, I mean ***I will not know the number of hashtags, so I'll have to add them before the cell shows up on screen, and so it makes each cell's size, different***

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108507/discussion-between-earl-grey-and-mehrdadmaskull).

Answer (score 0):

When you don't provide the estimated row-height, the cell height defaults to 44, and that's why you're getting a content height of 43.667.

You need to provide the estimated row height, which will be the height when there are no tags in the field provided. Then all that's needed to set the correct height dynamically is the right set of autolayout constraints to provide the `contentView`'s intrinsic size.

This will happen when you set a vertical space constraint between all the subviews of `contentView`, including a `topSpaceToSuperview` and `bottomSpaceToSuperview` to enable the AutoLayout engine to calculate the intrinsic content size.

**Edit**

I have analysed your constraints from the screenshot, and here are the relevant constraints you have added to calculate the cell height:

- Title.top = topMargin + 8
- bottomMargin = Share Button.bottom
- Link.centerY = Share Button.centerY
- Hashtags View.top = Title.bottom
- Date.top = Hashtags View.bottom + 15

Now here's a visual representation of these constraints:

TopMargin

|

Title

|

Hashtags View

|

Date

!!! **broken link** !!!

Link — Share Button

|

BottomMargin

The broken link prevents the Layout Engine from calculating the cell height. You need to fix the broken link in the vertical layout, for instance, by setting `Date.centerY = shareButton.centerY`, or by setting `Date.top = HashtagsView.bottom`.

Comment: I think I've tried that by explicitly giving each subview explicit heights. I'm going to try that again when I wake up and confirm it.

Comment: Apart from each subview having explicit heights, there has to be a vertical space constraint between the subviews and a top-space and a bottom-space constraint to the superview (from the topmost subview and the bottommost subview, respectively).

Comment: I tried giving vertical space constraints and explicit height on the hashtagsView with estimatedRowHeight set, but setting estimatedRowHeight unables me to get the correct width of cell.contentView! I don't know why estimatedRowHeight changes contentView's width! It gives me this: 
Content: (0.0, 0.0, 240.0, 119.666666666667)
Look at my updated post above

Comment: I'm not using .xib files. I'm going to upload a screenshot of my constraints. Check for update #2 on my post.

Comment: There are missing constraints which prevent the AutoLayout engine from successfully calculating the content height. I have edited my answer to elaborate.

Comment: Good catch, but that didn't change anything. I've noticed something weird in the tableViewCell's configureCell method. Please check my post with yet another screenshot.