# How to create a dynamic size UITableViewCell in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to create a table with dynamic size and views programmatically. The problem is auto height does not work. How do I make sure cell height stays correct when I create the cell with more views.

Here is what it looks like:
[image: Here is what it looks like:]

Here is my code:

```
import SnapKit
class FeedTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 500
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("appDataCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! AppDataTableViewCell
        let view =  cell.inner
        cell.ivLogo.kf_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: "http://creativosestrategicos.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/sample-logo-black16-300x58.png")!)
        cell.tvLabel.text = "Post Title"


        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Test"
        view.addSubview(label)
        label.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.top.equalTo(view)
            make.left.equalTo(view)
            make.right.equalTo(view)
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Here is my storyboard:
[image: Here is my storyboard]

Comment: This link may help you to calculate height of dynamic cell 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/36095091/3918500

Answer (score 0):

you should override the height method

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100 /// 100 is your value here
    }
```

Comment: But it is not static. The views are added programmatically, so it should be dynamic size.

Comment: calculate the value and pass it to that function then

Comment: I prefer to use UITableViewAutomaticDimension because the inner views will get extremely complicated and it will be difficult to calculate the values.

Comment: why do you want to add view programmatically? I think you should put the views in prototype cell and set data for it in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: They are loaded from server and depends on data.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong delegate method use tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: and return UITableViewAutomaticDimension.This will work only when you have given the correct constraints